# How to disable mail transport agent from starting up in Ubuntu?

Tags: sendmail, email-server

I installed sendmail on ubuntu 9.04 on my laptop computer.   My php mail() function still doesn't work from localhost, so I want to disable the auto start up of mail transport agent during system boot.

How do I disable the auto start up of the mail transport agent?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sudo update-rc.d sendmail disable
```

But I don't see how this is going to help your non-working mail() function.

Comment: Perhaps he found an alternative like a SMTP server somewhere else he could use and he is just trying to clean up?

Comment: thanks, that worked.  Actually, I'll ask about the mail function another time.   I couldn't get sendmail working on my localhost, so i figured I'll get rid of it for now because it was slowing down my system boot up.

Answer (score 1):

To make sendmail work with php, edit your php.ini file:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Use ctrl+W to search for "sendmail_". Remove the comment (#) before "sendmail_from" and "sendmail_path" and modify them like so:

```
sendmail_from = php@hostname
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t
```

You can replace "php@hostname" with your own.

To make sendmail boot faster, check your hostname with (or just look in /etc/hostname):

```
hostname
```

Then edit /etc/hosts:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Make sure it contains the following lines (you might have additional info like localhost.localdomain, if you have a domain):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 hostname
```